# Javascript alert not including var

Tags: javascript

So if I type into a box:

open google.com

I want the javascript to recognize "open google.com" when I type it and I want it to alert that to me. But I don't know how to make it alert google.com without having "open" before it.

```
var varopen = "open";
if (result.match(varopen)) {
    alert(result);
}
```

I want to display "result" without displaying "varopen".

Basically I want alert(result - varopen) to work but that doesn't work. PS I don't know anything about javascript.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please also include more code and create a JSFiddle. Thanks. :)

Comment: @zerkms it's true your a bit harsh... "You don't know and don't want to learn - so hire someone." How do you know he doesn't want to learn? I only agree with no. 1, "your explanation is not clear at all."

Comment: @Fridder but your language is inexcusable.

Comment: @zerkms Just because the problem seems simple or under researched to you does not mean that Fridder has not made an effort. One of the best things about this site is that it can help you when you not only don't know the answer, but also don't know how to find it. It would be better to try to find out more and editor the question than to dismiss it as bad.

Comment: @Fridder: It is helpful if you include the entire code for what you are trying to acheive. In the above code it is not obvious what `result` contains. Furthermore, you talk about a textbox, but none of the code posted relates to a textbox. Describing your higher level goals as well as posting all of the code you have so far will allow people to help you with better ways of approaching the problem, as well as solving the specific problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first instance of `varopen` from your string:

```
alert(result.replace(varopen, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Just use the replace method of the string result to replace varopen with nothing.

```
var result = ""
var varopen = "open ";
result = result.replace(varopen,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var varopen = "open";
if (result.match(varopen)) {
    alert(result.replace("open ", ""));
}
```